# Why LDAP authentication routine typically use two binds?

Tags: java, spring, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap

I am using Spring LDAP and I see everyone using two binds.The first bind as a service account and the second bind as the user with the password given. But I see that user validation against the password in ldap can be performed even without the first bind.

Can anyone please explain why we follow two binds in ldap? And what is the significance of the first bind using service account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For authentication in LDAP you need to have DN and password.

Usually the reason for 2 binds is that you do not have the DN - user name is not necessarily a part of the DN. Therefore you have to use service account to find the user (DN) by some attribute, e.g. "mail={mail}" and afterwards verify the password for the found DN by making another bind.

It is possible to use a single bind in 2 situations:

1. You may determine the DN without a search, e.g. if uid+password are used for login and "uid" is a part of the DN and the LDAP hierarchy is flat for all users, e.g. "uid={uid},ou=users,...".
2. You do not perform password check by a bind but fetch the password hash via the service account and compare the hash yourself.

Comment: I would not reconmend comparing the hash in your application as that would mean that you need a privileged account to look up the password. Normaly the password attribute can only be read by tge user itself and an admin account in LDAP. Therfore you can read the password attribute only by using an admin account in your application to bind and then search for the user. That therefore exposes a risk to read all password in the LDAP and crack them. I'd always use the 2bind way as it's the most secure way.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to authenticate against LDAP.
You can do it by fetching the user password and match it in your software (one bind) or you can do it by binding against the LDAP with the user credentials (two binds).

That two binding thing works as the follows:

1) Take username and search it in LDAP (Bind 1 with service account)
2) Authenticate using password (Bind 2 with user account)

Regards

Shelltux

Comment: That one-bind thing ist the "PasswordComparisonAuthenticator" and that two-bind thing is the "BindAuthenticator"